# Who invented the Python Seaborn library?

Tags: seaborn

I'm writing a review paper on python libraries and can't find any information about seaborn, particularly who invented it, what year and why was it named like that? Any leads? Thank you!

Comment: Aaahmm... 10 sec google search? [Enough?](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/master/LICENSE). Hint: he is even an active SO-user. Look who is the seaborn-tag [top-user](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/seaborn/topusers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the [official site](https://seaborn.pydata.org/introduction.html) there is a copyright to Michael Waskom.
Google provides a couple of links for this person:

- https://github.com/mwaskom
- https://twitter.com/michaelwaskom
- http://www.cns.nyu.edu/~mwaskom (doesn't work for me now)

For questions about the name you should probably contact the author. I believe he will answer you.)

Answer (score -1):

There is some information online saying it is named after a character in The West Wing TV show: Samuel Norman Seaborn, which is also why it's imported as
'sns'

Comment: This may be true, but this isn't really the answer to who takes credit for the library development.

Comment: @n.shabankin: The original question does ask, “… and why was it named like that?” That said, this question is likely off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).